# How do I use NSISO8601DateFormatter to parse a date from a string in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, date, format

For the life of me I can't understand why `dateFromString` is producing a nil value in the code below.

```
NSString* timeStampValue = @"20230917120009.289Z";
    NSString* dateString = [timeStampValue substringToIndex:8];
    NSISO8601DateFormatter* formatter = [[NSISO8601DateFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatter setFormatOptions:NSISO8601DateFormatWithFullDate];
    NSDate* dateOfLastVerification = [formatter dateFromString:dateString];
```

First I tried converting the entire string `timeStampValue` and set the format options accordingly. I was expecting that to work because, as far as I'm aware, this string is in valid ISO8601 format. Technically its using GeneralizedTime syntax but it doesn't seem like that should matter. But that threw a nil pointer.

Then I decided to just extract the date substring (I don't necessarily need the time and time zone data) and specify NSISO8601DateFormatWithFullDate as the only option. That should be my safest bet, right? Well, dateFromString threw nil in that scenario as well. I tried setting the format options on the formatter directly and it made no difference:

```
formatter.formatOptions = NSISO8601DateFormatWithFullDate
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*"this string is in valid ISO8601 format"* - actually, no. To make it valid you need the `T` between the date and time. The valid string would be:

```
NSString* timeStampValue = @"20230917T120009.289Z"; // Note the added T
```

Even with that, you need very specific format options for the string to be recognized properly. You need the following options:

- NSISO8601DateFormatWithYear
- NSISO8601DateFormatWithMonth
- NSISO8601DateFormatWithDate
- NSISO8601DateFormatWithTime
- NSISO8601DateFormatWithFractionalSeconds
- NSISO8601DateFormatWithTimeZone

If you apply all of those options to the `formatOptions` property of the formatter, along with adding the needed `T` in the string, you will then be able to convert the string to an `NSDate`.

```objc
NSString* timeStampValue = @"20230917T120009.289Z";
NSISO8601DateFormatter* formatter = [[NSISO8601DateFormatter alloc] init];
formatter.formatOptions = NSISO8601DateFormatWithYear | NSISO8601DateFormatWithMonth | NSISO8601DateFormatWithDay | NSISO8601DateFormatWithTime | NSISO8601DateFormatWithFractionalSeconds | NSISO8601DateFormatWithTimeZone;
NSDate* dateOfLastVerification = [formatter dateFromString:timeStampValue];
```

Note that in order to use `NSISO8601DateFormatWithFullDate`, the string must have the date in the format "yyyy-MM-dd". If that's the only option you specify then the string can only contain the date and nothing else.

---

If you wanted to use the `NSISO8601DateFormatter` without needing to specify any format options, your string needs to be in the format "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZZZZZ".

---

A helpful debugging technique when working out issues with parsing a date string is to see what output you get converting an `NSDate` into an `NSString` with your date formatter. If the resulting output doesn't match the input you are trying to parse then you know you have the wrong format options or an invalid input string.